# iPhone slide-up view controller for audio player controls?

Tags: iphone, audio, uiview, controller

I have a short audio clip that plays when a button is pressed. I want to create a slide-up controller from the bottom that contains a pause/play button and a slider bar displaying the length of the audio. I also want the view behind the controller to remain scrollable while the controller is visible. I believe this excludes using a UIAlertView or UIActionSheetView as both cause the view below to remain static. What is the best way to implement this?

EDIT: i found a helpful tutorial here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/sliding-views-on-and-off-screen-creating-a-reusable-sliding-message-widget.html

and I was able to modify this to get something of what I want. However, if I would like to animate using a nib file where/how would i call this?

```
#import "SlidingMessageController.h"


@interface SlidingMessageController(private)
- (void)hideMsg;
@end

@implementation SlidingMessageController
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private Methods


- (void)hideMsg;
{
    // Slide the view off screen
    CGRect frame = self.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];

    frame.origin.y = 480;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    self.frame = frame;

    //to autorelease the Msg, define stop selector
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString*)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context 
{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    [self release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

- (id)initWithDirection:(int)dir;
//- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)msg
{
  if (self = [super init]) 
  {
      //Switch direction based on slideDirection konstant
      switch (dir) {
          case kSlideUp:    //slideup
              // Notice the view y coordinate is offscreen (480)
              // This hides the view

              // What should I be doing here if I want to get the nib file???       
              self.frame = CGRectMake(0,480,320, 90);
              [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
              [self setAlpha:.87];


              newY = 380;
              newX = 0;
              myDir = 0;
              break;
              default:
              break;
      }


  }

  return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Message Handling

- (void)showMsgWithDelay:(int)delay
{
//  UIView *view = self.view;
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];

    // Slide up based on y axis
    // A better solution over a hard-coded value would be to
    // determine the size of the title and msg labels and 
    // set this value accordingly

    frame.origin.y = newY;
    frame.origin.x = newX;
    self.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // Hide the view after the requested delay
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideMsg) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Cleanup

- (void)dealloc 
{
  if ([self superview])
    [self removeFromSuperview];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I recommend against doing this. It will be a confusing interface and will be difficult to control programatically. There is a reason that action sheets are modal.

Comment: If executed well it could certainly work imho. Let's say you press a button to start playback of an audio file. The controls then appear at the bottom of the screen so you can play/pause etc. at any time. Don't think this would confuse users. Again, if done correctly of course.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar to the NPR Music app. It's done quite nicely and I think it's a good solution to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with a "slide-up controller"? Just a view that slides up from the bottom? If so, you can just create a UIView with the buttons in it, and animate it. For the animation you can use UIView `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimations`.

Comment: I agree you will want to make your own view.  You could also do what apple does and make the control disappear after a short period rather than sliding up and down.  Then just have the control come up if the user taps (not scrolls) the existing scroller.